# How to call method EnableStatic() in C++?

Tags: c++, networking, ip

Like in the title.

I'm a not very experienced with classes and I have hard time with calling the function EnableStatic() from Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration class in  C++. So how to do it?

I would really appreciate an example or simple program with it!

---

Additional Info:

•I've tried use this part of calling code:

```
#define _WIN32_DCOM

#include <iostream>
#include <winsock.h>
#include <string>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <comdef.h>
#include <Wbemidl.h>
int maint()
{
UINT ipaddr = inet_addr("155.34.22.0");
UINT subnet = inet_addr("255.255.255.0");

Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration Adapter;
Adapter.EnableStatic(ipaddr,subnet);
system("pause");
}
```

•The method's website:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa390383(v=vs.85).aspx

---

*If anyone interested I'm inviting for a C++ [project](https://github.com/CubaQ/Nimfador) on GitHub*

Comment: What error(s) do you get?

Comment: Here is an example: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/387500/Cplusplus-WMI-EnableStatic-with-multiple-IPs

Comment: That looks like COM and *not* a typical C++ class where you can just declare an instance and call member functions.  You need to do much more than that if it's COM.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I've checked msdn documents and, indeed, it's COM object.